# find table row number from selected cell

Tags: excel, row, vba

How do I find the row number in a table (Excel 2010) from the selected cell.
I can find the sheet row number from `ActiveRow.Row` or `Selection.Row`. But I want to know what row number in the table this is.

Answer (score 15):

```
    Selection.Row - Selection.ListObject.Range.Row
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! ➕

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, try getting (active row - first row of table). That will give you the row number from the table.

Answer (score 1):

i am not a vba / excel expert but this might do the job: 
the answer is a bit late - but i ran into the same problem.
my function returns a listRow object, that is more powerful:

```
Sub testit()
    Dim myList As ListObject
    Dim myRow As ListRow
    'some reference to a listObject
    Set myList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("TableX")
    '
    'test the function
    Set myRow = FirstSelectedListRow(myList)
    '
    'select the row
    myRow.Select
    'get index within sheet
    MsgBox ("sheet row num " & myRow.Range.Row)

   ' get index within list
   MsgBox ("List row index " & myRow.Index)
End Sub
'return ListRow if at least one cell of one row is acitve
'return Nothing otherwise
Function FirstSelectedListRow(list As ListObject) As ListRow
    'default return
    Set FirstSelectedListRow = Nothing
    'declarations
    Dim activeRange As Range
    Dim activeListCells As Range
    Dim indexSelectedRow_Sheet As Long
    Dim indexFirstRowList_Sheet As Long
    Dim indexSelectedRow_List As Long
    'get current selection
    Set activeRange = Selection
    Set activeListCells = Intersect(list.Range, activeRange)
    'no intersection - test
    If activeListCells Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    indexSelectedRow_Sheet = activeRange.Row
    indexFirstRowList_Sheet = list.Range.Row
    indexSelectedRow_List = indexSelectedRow_Sheet - indexFirstRowList_Sheet
    Set FirstSelectedListRow = list.ListRows(indexSelectedRow_List)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, assuming that there is only one table in sheet. Otherwise You need to specify the table range.

```
Sub FindRowNoInTable()

Dim ObjSheet As Worksheet
Dim startRow, ActiveRow, ActiveCol
Dim ObjList As ListObject
Set ObjSheet = ActiveSheet
ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCol = ActiveCell.Column
For Each ObjList In ObjSheet.ListObjects
    Application.Goto ObjList.Range
    startRow = ObjList.Range.Row
Next
MsgBox (ActiveRow - startRow)
Cells(ActiveRow, ActiveCol).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

YourRange.row minus YourListObject.HeaderRowRange.row

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I landed here whilst searching for this, so ...

Simplest way I know:

```
    dim MyTable as listobject
    dim MyRow as integer

    ' Here your code or a manual action makes you end up on a random row
    ... Dostuffdostuffbleepbloop ...

    ' Find the row number you landed on within the table (the record number if you will)
    MyRow = MyTable.DataBodyRange().Row
```

That's it.

Pease note:

- This is done with Office 2019
- The brackets after *DataBodyRange* are **EMPTY.**
- The row counter is from ***DataBodyRange*** thus does NOT include the headers

Hope it helps someone.