# Use VBA Userform to update active row

Tags: vba, excel

I load the user form and edit the data when i click the update button the last row of the table is updated instead of the row i have selected

```
Private Sub UpdateExpenses_Click()

ModifyTableRow ExpensesTable.ListRows(CurrentRow).Range

UpdatePositionCaption

End Sub

Private Sub ModifyTableRow(TableRow As Range)

With TableRow

    .Cells(1, 1) = Calendar1.Value
    .Cells(1, 2) = StaffName.Value
    .Cells(1, 4) = SystemID.Value
    .Cells(1, 6) = SystemAEnd.Value
    .Cells(1, 7) = SystemBEnd.Value
    .Cells(1, 3) = CircuitDesc.Value
    .Cells(1, 9) = CircuitStatus.Value
    .Cells(1, 10) = Comments.Value
    .Cells(1, 8) = TypeofCircuit.Value
    .Cells(1, 5) = ChannelNum.Value



End With

ChangeRecord.Max = ExpensesTable.ListRows.Count
```

End Sub

any help with this code would be much appriciated

Comment: I suspect that when you called the form your "active row" lost focus

Comment: post the code of `ModifyTableRow`, or the relevant part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the code this solution worked for me

```
Option Explicit
Private ExpensesTable As ListObject
Private CurrentRow As Long
Private WithEvent`enter code here`s Calendar1 As cCalendar

Private Sub UpdateExpenses_Click()
CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(CurrentRow, 2) = Calendar1.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 3) = Me.StaffName.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 4) = Me.CircuitDesc.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 5) = Me.SystemID.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 6) = Me.ChannelNum.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 7) = Me.SystemAEnd.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 8) = Me.SystemBEnd.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 9) = Me.TypeofCircuit.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 10) = Me.CircuitStatus.Value
Cells(CurrentRow, 11) = Me.Comments.Value
Unload ExpensesForm

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the active row of the current table.  Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232250/find-table-row-number-from-selected-cell)
Originally answered by @Anand

```
Sub FindRowNoInTable()

Dim ObjSheet As Worksheet
Dim startRow, ActiveRow, ActiveCol
Dim ObjList As ListObject
Set ObjSheet = ActiveSheet
ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCol = ActiveCell.Column
For Each ObjList In ObjSheet.ListObjects
        Application.Goto ObjList.Range
        startRow = ObjList.Range.Row
Next
Debug.Print (ActiveRow - startRow)

End Sub
```

Then put (ActiveRow - startRow) into the variable "CurrentRow"

Comment: I added the above code and got Compile error: variable not defined

Comment: All the variables in this subroutine are defined by a dim statement so you are not getting that error from this code.  Is there any worksheet subroutines working in the background?  Something else is causing that error.  Tested this code several times, with and without "Option Explicit"